# Rundeck Community Welcome Project ends in an ERROR interceptors.AuthorizationInterceptor

Tags: rundeck

I performed the following commands:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

However, I get an error:

```
rundeck  | [2023-04-03T09:21:06,530] ERROR interceptors.AuthorizationInterceptor - (unauthenticated) UNAUTHORIZED for api/invalid
```

and the client is exited.

```
rundeck  | [2023-04-03T09:21:06,478] INFO  api.requests "GET /api/26/system/info" 172.22.0.3 http admin form 26  (/ ms-rest-js/1.7.0 Node/v12.20.1 OS/(x64-Linux-5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2))
client   | Rundeck started!!!
client   | ----------------------------------
client   | Importing Users
client   | ----------------------------------
client   | ----------------------------------
client   | importing users
client   | ----------------------------------
client   | importing user: alice
client   | email: alice@rundeck.io
client   | {}
client   | importing user: bonny
client   | email: bonny@rundeck.io
client   | {}
client   | importing user: charles
client   | email: charles@rundeck.io
client   | {}
client   | importing user: donny
client   | email: donny@rundeck.io
client   | {}
client   | importing user: eliot
client   | email: eliot@rundeck.io
client   | {}
client   | importing user: fred
client   | email: fred@rundeck.io
client   | {}
rundeck  | [2023-04-03T09:21:06,530] ERROR interceptors.AuthorizationInterceptor - (unauthenticated) UNAUTHORIZED for api/invalid
rundeck  | [2023-04-03T09:21:06,531] ERROR interceptors.AuthorizationInterceptor - (unauthenticated) UNAUTHORIZED for api/invalid
rundeck  | [2023-04-03T09:21:06,531] ERROR interceptors.AuthorizationInterceptor - (unauthenticated) UNAUTHORIZED for api/invalid
rundeck  | [2023-04-03T09:21:06,532] ERROR interceptors.AuthorizationInterceptor - (unauthenticated) UNAUTHORIZED for api/invalid
rundeck  | [2023-04-03T09:21:06,534] ERROR interceptors.AuthorizationInterceptor - (unauthenticated) UNAUTHORIZED for api/invalid
rundeck  | [2023-04-03T09:21:06,535] ERROR interceptors.AuthorizationInterceptor - (unauthenticated) UNAUTHORIZED for api/invalid
client exited with code 0
```

This is my environment.

Rundeck Tag 4.9.0.

```
Linux LT432629 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 02:56:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Docker Compose version v2.15.1
Server: Docker Desktop
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.23
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.10
  Git commit:       6051f14
  Built:            Thu Jan 19 17:32:04 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.18
  GitCommit:        2456e983eb9e37e47538f59ea18f2043c9a73640
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

I am trying to make a test run with the Rundeck Community Welcome Project to understand the ACL...

I have used `docker compose build` and `docker compose up` after cloning the project.

Running Containers

```
NAME                IMAGE                               COMMAND                  SERVICE             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
ciao                brotandgames/ciao                   "./start.sh"             ciao                33 hours ago        Up 33 hours         0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp
mysql               mysql:8                             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   mysql               33 hours ago        Up 33 hours         3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
node1               welcome-project-community-node      "/bin/sh -c '/usr/lo…"   node                33 hours ago        Up 33 hours         0.0.0.0:58322->22/tcp
node2               welcome-project-community-node2     "/bin/sh -c '/usr/lo…"   node2               33 hours ago        Up 33 hours         0.0.0.0:58321->22/tcp
rundeck             welcome-project-community-rundeck   "/tini -- docker-lib…"   rundeck             33 hours ago        Up 33 hours         0.0.0.0:4440->4440/tcp
```

Client Container is stopped

```
ciao                brotandgames/ciao                   "./start.sh"             ciao                33 hours ago        Up 33 hours               0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp
client              welcome-project-community-client    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   client              33 hours ago        Exited (0) 33 hours ago
mysql               mysql:8                             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   mysql               33 hours ago        Up 33 hours               3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
node1               welcome-project-community-node      "/bin/sh -c '/usr/lo…"   node                33 hours ago        Up 33 hours               0.0.0.0:58322->22/tcp
node2               welcome-project-community-node2     "/bin/sh -c '/usr/lo…"   node2               33 hours ago        Up 33 hours               0.0.0.0:58321->22/tcp
rundeck             welcome-project-community-rundeck   "/tini -- docker-lib…"   rundeck             33 hours ago        Up 33 hours               0.0.0.0:4440->4440/tcp
```

Comment: Hi! What containers are you seeing running after deploying the welcome project?

Comment: Hi, I added the containers in the description. The Client Container is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

The client container objective is to "inject" data into the Rundeck / Nodes containers. At the end, the container will exit. After that, you will see the rundeck, ciao, MySQL, and node containers running to start the learning the [tutorial](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/#getting-started).